# float a <p> and <ul> element on same line

Tags: html, css, floating

I already read all the questions and answers that look like my problem, but i still can't seem to figure out why my piece of code is not working.

I would really be grateful if someone could help me out.

What I'm trying to do is to get a ul element floating after a p element.
See the code snippet aat: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6D6p/66/

html:

```
<div class="gf-sosumi">
  <p>Copyright © 2014 Van Straten Fotografie. All rights reserved.</p>
  <ul class="piped">
    <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

css:

```
#globalfooter .gf-sosumi p { float: left;}
#globalfooter ul.piped a { float:left; padding: 0 0 0 1.5em; margin-left: 1.5em; border-left: 1px solid #212121; }

.piped li { float: left;}
.piped a { float: left; border-left: 1px solid #212121; padding: 0 0 0 0.75em; margin-left: 0.75em; }
```

it results in the list on the next line in stead of after the p element.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that the jsfiddle doesn't show it the way you want it? How do you want it to look?

Comment: Solution for what I wanted was in the answer of @agconti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css:

```
.gf-sosumi p, .piped {display: inline-block;}
```

example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Y6D6p/69/ (make sure you open the results window wide enough)

Comment: Thanks agconti, this works even better than the previous answer. Since I could not simply extract the p ul and li from the other classes like Niels Keurentjes did.

Comment: no problem,happy to help! @NielsKeurentjes was right about avoiding floats though! Watch out for those in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `float` for trivial tasks like just forcing stuff next to eachother, easier to use `display:inline-block` for that. Just applying that to the `p`, `ul` and `li` elements will fix it.

[Sample updated simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/Y6D6p/68/).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exaclty what i needed. I'm going to read some more information about the display: css that's one i never used before. probably this will save me a lot of troubles on other places also.